# how to return result from async method cosmodb?

Tags: c#, linq, document, azure-cosmosdb

After doing a reasearch i found that document db api supports grouping, so i have implemented using linq,

How can i see the results got from the dataase?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            var result =  p.GetStartedDemo().Wait();
        }

        private async Task GetStartedDemo()
        {
            var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey);
            var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("testdb", "retrieve");
            var result = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Login>(documentUri)
                  .Where(i => i.logevent == "success" && i._ts > 1517405472 && i._ts <= 1518010272)
                  .GroupBy(t => t._ts);

            return result;
        }
```

**ERROR:**

var result =  p.GetStartedDemo().Wait();

Cannot assign implicitly typed code variable. what is the issue?

Comment: Task means that the method doesn't return a value it just returns a task that tells you when it's done. Task<T> is what it should return where T is the type of the object you're returning

Comment: i want to see the output of the returned results. how to do that

Comment: i am stuck with this, atleast guide me

Comment: I don't know the details of cosmosdb, I haven't used it. I'm on my phone ATM so if no one helps before my laptop finishes updating ill take another look. Sounds like you need do a bit of learning on Tasks and async programming

Comment: @Dave please, i am stuck

Comment: what about : `var result =  p.GetStartedDemo().Result;`

Comment: The docs say you are using an obsolete API. See the updated async docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-samples#document-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the "Wait" method of a task object and trying to assign its return to the "result" variable.
If you check the `Task.Wait()` [method signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see it has no return:

```
public void Wait();
```

I'm your example there is no need for your `GetStartedDemo` to return a Task and to be "async", you are not doing any asynchronous operation inside it. You can simply return the for you want fit the caller method.

If you want to learn about CosmosDB I suggest checking the [Microsoft documentation about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/)

For your code to work you could simply change the return type of your method to actually match what you are returning:

```
// Considering that Login._t is of type "long":
private IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, Login>> GetStartedDemo()
{ /* ... */ }
```

Then, in your Main method, you can print the items grouped by `Login._t` :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        var result =  p.GetStartedDemo();
        foreach (var group in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Group: " + group.Key);

            foreach (Login login in group)
               Console.WriteLine("    " + login.SomeProperty); // print something from the login object.
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no namespace Grouping

Comment: Sorry, fixed it, the type is the interface IGrouping: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks that worked i was able to fix it. can you lok this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676519/query-expression-is-invalid-cosmosdb/48678821#48678821

Comment: i need to add a count for the date

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you wanna count the amount of Login records with the same date?